# Как узнать дату регистрации vk?

Tags: php, вконтакте, vkontakte-api

Как узнают дату эти приложения: [Ссылка1](http://vk.com/app3906122) ? Подскажите, может всё таки с помощью какого то метода api?

Comment: Судя по том, что проги дают разные результаты, четких данных нет. Значит, ответ @barseon можно принимать ))

Comment: Создал 10 фейковых страниц, записал в блокнот точную дату регистрации (год, месяц, день, час, минуту, секунду). Профили были пустые, без записей и фотографий. На два профиля через 5 дней написал первую запись на стене.
Потом через 20, 30, 100 дней проверил через сторонние сервисы, типа vkreg.ru, vkmaster.zf-projects.ru/users-dreg и другие.
Результат, точное совпадение, с точностью до секунды, результат правильный.
Свою страницу я помню в 2011 году регистрировал, и там тоже результат был правильный, СМС отыскал на телефоне от 2011 года с инвайтом. Тоже совпадение прям точное, даже секунда совпа

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Есть такой зверь - FOAF (Friend of a Friend).
 
Если введёте такой запрос:

```
http://vk.com/foaf.php?id=1
```

В ответ получите xml-файл
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Про FOAF на [хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/18263/) и в [Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/FOAF)
Описание [спецификации на Яндксе](https://tech.yandex.ru/blogs/doc/indexation/reference/foaf-standard-tags-docpage/)
[Официальная спецификация FOAF](http://xmlns.com/foaf/spec/)

Answer (score 3):

В api данной функции нет, но id каждого юзера инкрементный, поэтому коррелирует с датой регистрации, можно примерно вычислить (если знать дату регистрации любого другого).

Comment: Всё же хотелось бы узнать более подробнее как её найти. Кстати, в выше упомянутом сервисе отображается еще и время.

Answer (score 3):

Случайным образом обнаружился новый непубличный метод `memories.get` из ветки `memories`. Насколько мне известно, он создавался для [приложения о воспоминаниях](https://vk.com/memories) личной страницы.

При запросе получаем много json-данных, но необходим только параметр `registered`, который при успешном результате возвращает unix-время регистрации своей страницы.

Запрос через метод `execute`:

```
return API.memories.get().registered;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Из **минусов** стоит отметить, что метод позволяет узнать только дату своей страницы, а из **плюсов** то, что не нужно делать парсинг через FOAF.